# Getting the updated value from Surfaceview class

Tags: android

I have declared an global int counter variable like this :

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
public int counter = 0;
```

I am updating its value onclick:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    for (Balloon aMBalloonArray : mBalloonArray) {
        if (aMBalloonArray.isCollition(x, y)) {
            aMBalloonArray.reposition();
            popSound.start();
            counter = counter + 1;
            Log.d("GamePanel", "Score:" + counter);
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I use this method to get the value:

```
public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
```

but it displays 0 and not the updated value. can you tell me what to do and how to display the updated variable. Thanks in advance.

calling getcounter():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //set to full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.final_score);


    String score = getIntent().getStringExtra("SCORE");
    finalScoreTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.final_score);
    gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
    finalScoreTextView.setText(gamePanel.getCounter());
    finalScoreTextView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: may be you are calling `getCounter()` method every time on a new `GamePanel` object. Post the code where you call `getCounter()` method

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but i have added that code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: on every execution of `onCreate()` you are creating a new `GamePanel` object with counter 0. so it returns 0 always.

Comment: Thanks I got it using the SharedPreferences :)